# input type for implementing a parse cmdline method

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I'm building a command prompt shell.
In the code, I'm implementing a method:

```
int parsecmd(const char *cmdline, char *arglist[])
```

It's supposed to parse the command line input which I will store in a char[] and return the number of arguments

Now, the question is that I'm not sure what should I put as parameter when I'm calling this method. The following is my code to get input in main method:

```
char input[MAXLINE];
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
```

Should I create a pointer array that points to *input?

```
char *buffer = input;
int count;
count = parsecmd(inputP,buffer);
```

I know it's wrong. How should I do it properly?

Comment: you don't have a list of strings, only a string. You have to split elements first, and that's not trivial if you support quoting like any good command line needs to do. But maybe some other Q/A can help here.

Comment: Are you familiar with structures?  How are you going to handle error reporting?  How will you know how many arguments there are?  What do you do if there are multiple command on a single line, with & or ; or || or && separators?  What do you do if the command isn't complete?

Comment: Here is a sample input:  "ls -s >lsoutput; sort -n<lsoutput; emacs &".  I will parse the input in the parsecmd method and return the number of arguments in int.